# Entity Framework Custom Navigational Properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, properties

Is there a way to map below `ClassA.BId` to `ClassB.BetaId` ?
`BetaId` in `ClassB` is not primary key. Thus, mapping in following way end up in "*The ForeignKeyAttribute is not valid"* exception. Note that there is no foreign key relationship in these 2 classes. For some reason I must not map `ClassA.BId` to `ClassB.Id` because these 2 field is unrelated but I need to custom map `ClassA.BId` to `ClassB.BetaId` due to these 2 field is related. However, The `Id` in `ClassB` must remain as primary key.

Note: I'm using Entity Framework 6

```
[Table("A")]
public class ClassA{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }


    public int BId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BId")]
    public virtual B B { get; set; }
}

[Table("B")]
public class ClassB{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int BetaId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If B.BetaID is unique you can declare it to be the Key.  Otherwise EF Core supports Foreign Key properties referencing Alternate Keys.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/alternate-keys

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this is only true for EF Core, and not for Entity Framework 6, as the "Unique Index" constraint feature is missing.

Comment: Only EF Core supports Foreign Key Properties referring to an Alternate Key.  In EF6 Foreign Key Properties must refer to the one-and-only "Entity Key".  However you may choose any key you like to be _the_ "Entity Key".  So in this case you could move the KeyAttribute from Id to BetaId, but you would have to use BetaId as the only key for that entity.